# How to put a file on the servlet context path with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I am trying to add BlazeDS to a Spring Boot application. I have added the `MessageBrokerServlet' in my configuration for this:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageBrokerRegistration()
{
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new MessageBrokerServlet(), "/messagebroker/*");
    Map<String,String> params = Maps.newHashMap();
    params.put( "services.configuration.file", "/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml" );
    registration.setInitParameters(params);
    return registration;
}
```

The servlet gets loaded, but fails at runtime with:

```
MessageBrokerServlet in application 'undefined' failed to initialize due to runtime exception:   
Exception: flex.messaging.config.ConfigurationException: Please specify a 
valid 'services.configuration.file' in web.xml. You specified '{0}'.
This is not a valid file system path reachable via the app server and 
is also not a path to a resource in your J2EE application archive.
```

Looking through the source code of BlazeDS, I see that in the end, the code uses `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream(path)`. How can I make the embedded tomcat in Spring Boot return something on that call?

I am using Spring Boot 1.1.1 which uses embedded Tomcat 7.0.54

Comment: hello! did you figure it out how to do it? 
how did you map the URL onto the broker?

Comment: I am no longer on that project. It has been too long ago to remember if I ever got it working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet context resources should work in a war at least. Stick them in `src/main/webapp` (for a standard build layout).

Comment: I am not using a war. Any option then?

Comment: AFAIK it should still work. Where did you put the resources, and where did they end up in your jar?

Comment: I've put them in `src/main/resources`

Comment: I run from within IntelliJ, don't know if that should make a difference?

Comment: Did you try "java -jar ..."? Yes it should make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this recently using the following:

```
@Lazy
@Bean(name="messageBroker")
public MessageBrokerFactoryBean messageBrokerFactoryBean() {
    MessageBrokerFactoryBean messageBrokerFactory = new MessageBrokerFactoryBean();
    messageBrokerFactory.setServicesConfigPath("classpath:/flex/services-config.xml");
    return  messageBrokerFactory;
}
```

Where services-config.xml (and my other flex config files) are in src/main/resources/flex

Hope this hope someone else!